# "You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error."

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I tried to build my project with the command `ng build`.
I get this error :

> `You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.`

I have already tried:

```
npm install
ng serve
```

It shows me this error :

> `npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-116-generic`
>
> `npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"`
>
> `npm ERR! node v9.10.1`
>
> `npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10`
> `npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/ng`
> `npm ERR! code EEXIST`

And my package.json :

```json
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"

"@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
"cli-color": "^1.2.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"matrix-js-sdk": "^0.8.5",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
"olm": "https://matrix.org/packages/npm/olm/olm-2.2.2.tgz",
"readline": "^1.3.0",
"rxjs": "^5.4.1",
"socket.io-client": "^2.0.3",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"

"@angular/cli": "1.2.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.0.4",
"tslint": "~5.3.2",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
```

Comment: Please show us your `package.json`

Comment: @UncleDave I updated my post

Comment: You need to execute `ng serve` in the working directory.

Comment: @Vikas I have already try `ng serve` in my working directory, and I have this error : `You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.`

Comment: Oops my bad!! Then refer the link given by @ R. Richards.